# python unicode regular expressions

Tags: python, regex

I read a file with the code below and then I want to find words in the file using re library. The file contains Turkish characters. So I decode file using utf-8. re library doesn't know Turkish character.  Below code isn't working.

```
    text= unicodedata.normalize("NFKD",codecs.open(os.path.abspath("texts/kopru1.txt"),"rb").read().decode("utf-8"))
    text=text.replace("\r\n"," ").lower()
    aa= re.findall(ur"[a-zçşıöü]+", text,re.UNICODE)
```

Although "**ayşe**" is a word, this word seems as of "**ays**" and "**e**".

Comment: Could you give some example data and tell us what you want to do?

Comment: example string is "ayşe kulin köprü". I want to find words in this string.

Comment: If you want to split by word why not use `text.split(" ")`?

Answer (score 5):

Use the escape sequence `\w` which means "a letter of any kind." Just getting an example sentence from wikipedia:

```
>>> text = u'Türkî-i çin (güzel güneş) terkiplerinde de gördüğümüz'
>>> re.findall(r'\w+', text, re.UNICODE)
['Türkî', 'i', 'çin', 'güzel', 'güneş', 'terkiplerinde', 'de', 'gördüğümüz']
```

Comment: I had done before. And again I did. But the code isn't still working.

Comment: @hinzir what does your `text` variable look like before you try to match on it?

Comment: @hinzir Oh, right. I've updated my reply with additional hints. See if it helps.

Comment: @kgr you are wrong about replace method. http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.replace "Return a copy of string s with all occurrences of substring old replaced by new. "

Comment: @hinzir That's really, really weird. When I tested yesterday I could swear it wouldn't return a new string, but now that I try it does.

Comment: That's OK. It isn't still working :) By the by what version of Python does you have installed? I have 2.7

Comment: 2.7 and 3.2. I have tested my regex with both and it works for me. That's what leads me to believe there is something wrong with your text data.